# Can't display the thumbnails of HEVC Main10P and VP9 codec video

Tags: nautilus, ffmpeg, codecs, webm, hevc

I hate totem player, it is useless to me, so I installed the ffmpegthumbnailer, removed totem player, and changed the default thumbnailer to it by following steps.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpegthumbnailer gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Then deleted thumbnail cache:

```
rm ~/.thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
rm ~/.thumbnails/normal/*
```

I then made a change in /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer

from this:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
```

to this:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
```

But it can't generate the thumbnails from HEVC Main10P and VP9 codec videos, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anybody answer me???

Comment: Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?  If Wily try adding: `sudo apt-get install  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.4LTS

Comment: It can't find that package.

Comment: Trusty does not have FFmpeg so you have this from PPA? If so you need appropriate support from FFmpeg for hevc and VP9...

Comment: Yes, I have installed ffmpeg 3.0.0 from ppa

Comment: There is a similar package called libavcodec-ffmpeg56, and it has been installed.

Comment: Is there any hope?

Comment: There is always hope :). Which PPA?

Comment: This one: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, I need to install the newer version of ffmpegthumbnailer and libffmpegthumbnailer4.

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/testing6/+build/7730885

Just download them and install.