# Can't generate thumbnails from some mkv files

Tags: nautilus, vlc, thumbnails, mkv, hevc

I've been using Ubuntu for a time but still not that professional one.

My problem -that I've been stuck with last two days- is I downloaded an MKV video with HEVC stream which is unknown to VLC, but by applying some tools and trying others I resolved the problem with video code, but for the audio,  it's still UNDF to VLC.

But I did that too by updating VLC to the latest version.
there is only one thing left. The thumbnails of videos couldn't be created, just from them, so I've tried to change the thumbnails creator to `ffmpegthumbnailer`. That didn't work too. 
I don't know if I should to mention that **totem** can't play these videos, and the only way to watch them is by using VLC. So I've looked for how to generate thumbnails from VLC instead of Totem or `ffmpegthumbnailer` but I didn't get to anywhere.

Any help would make me grateful.
Thank you.

I am using, 
 Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit,
 GNOME Shell 3.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/750276/229954

and it works for me.

Thank you: