# Mkv thumbnails are not generating at all

Tags: nautilus, video, 17.04, thumbnails, mkv

After updating to Ubuntu 17.04 my `.mkv` files aren't showing any thumbnails

**What have I tried so far?**

1. Installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` that didn't work.
2. Rebooted after installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
3. Tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/750276/665251) but it's for **Trusty** not 17.04
4. Tried changing thumbnail size is nautilus preferences.

as of yet, nothing has helped

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Failed thumbnail creation attempts are cached to prevent repeated attempts for performance. So those files are still ignored after you've fixed thumbnail creation.
Those failed files are stored in `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail`, delete one or all.

Also, there's a file size limit in *Preferences -> Search & Preview*(Gnome file manager previously called Nautilus), usually files larger than 10MB are ignored in thumbnail creation. Maximum size can be set to 4GB.